# How to display MySQL table in React.js table?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, typescript, bootstrap-4

I have created a simple web application that connects successfully to MySQL database. I would now like to render the table `availabilties` so that it displays nicely on the webpage  - ideally with a bootstrap class. Below is a code snippet where I display the header columns followed by a single `<td>` element that should render the unique `id` for each value in the table.

```
render() {
    return (
      <main className="container my-5">
        <h1 className="text-primary text-center">Current Availability</h1>
        <table className="table table-dark">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th scope="col">ID</th>
              <th scope="col">Queue</th>
              <th scope="col">CallDate</th>
              <th scope="col">TimeStart</th>
              <th scope="col">SecsFromMidnight</th>
              <th scope="col">TimeEnd</th>
              <th scope="col">EndSeconds</th>
              <th scope="col">TimeSlotCapacity</th>
              <th scope="col">Available</th>
              <th scope="col">Pending</th>
              <th scope="col">CallsCommitted</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <td>
              {this.state.availabilities.map(availability => {
                return <td>{availability.id}</td>;
              })}
            </td>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </main>
    );
  }
}
```

In its current form, it appears as per below:

[image]

I would like it so the ID values are listed vertically. When I am assisted with writing up this logic, I can then proceed to do this for the other database properties.

Interface for data:

```
export interface IAppState {
  availabilities: Array<{
    id: string;
    queue: string;
    call_date: string;
    time_start: string;
    start_seconds_from_midnight: string;
    time_end: string;
    end_seconds_from_midnight: string;
    timeslot_capacity: string;
    available: string;
    pending: string;
    calls_committed: string;
  }>;
}
```

ts file for retrieving data:

```
import { Connection } from "./index";

export const all = async () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    Connection.query("SELECT * FROM availability", (err, results) => {
      if (err) {
        return reject(err);
      }
      resolve(results);
    });
  });
};

export default {
  all
};
```

Comment: Can I see the code where you're fetching the data?

Comment: You have an array of `<td>`s nested inside another `<td>`, that's not right. Have a review of how the element hierarchy works for HTML tables, should give you an idea of how to render the elements: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp

Comment: I've updated the question @CameronRose

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<table className="table table-dark">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th scope="col">ID</th>
          <th scope="col">Queue</th>
          <th scope="col">CallDate</th>
          <th scope="col">TimeStart</th>
          <th scope="col">SecsFromMidnight</th>
          <th scope="col">TimeEnd</th>
          <th scope="col">EndSeconds</th>
          <th scope="col">TimeSlotCapacity</th>
          <th scope="col">Available</th>
          <th scope="col">Pending</th>
          <th scope="col">CallsCommitted</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        {this.state.availabilities.map(availability => {
          return (
            <tr>
              <td>{availability.id}</td>
            </tr>
          );
        })}
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

I ended up doing a bit more research and resolved the issue myself with the code sample above.